# Select2 input closes before selecting in android chrome mobile

Tags: jquery, ember.js, jquery-select2

I have a problem when using select2 4.0.5 in android chrome mobile, it closes right before I select an option. What should I do ? Do I need an upgrade or is there any suggestion ?